# Is it still possible to download Adele's full catalogue of custom content somewhere online?

Tags: the-sims-2

Once upon a time, [Adele](http://adelevk.com/) was one of the best custom content creators for The Sims 2. Unfortunately, her site has been down for a year or two now. I want to know if there is a -full collection- of her items uploaded somewhere else. I know she has some things on ModTheSims, but far from most things (particularly not the clothes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how complete it is, but there's quite a bit of it over on [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/?3k3p9jflpqmnf).  I found that by way of [this forum thread](http://www.digitalperversion.net/gardenofshadows/index.php?topic=21820.0) which contains many individual links that might be of use.  I found **that** link via [this thread](http://www.sailfinsims.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1856-where-to-find-content-from-inactive-sites-for-sims-2-and-3/), which catalogues Sims sites that have bitten the dust and where their content is backed up/currently located.

Unfortunately, by the very nature of content downloads, I can't really give a "timeless" answer here.  My suggestion would be to grab as much as you can, and back it up if you want to use it into the future.  Sites like these don't stick around forever, and the lifespan of disused content on the internet is generally fairly short.

Comment: That's perfect. I'm pretty sure that's 100% of the clothing items she had. I understand if the fleetingness of this makes this question innappropriate for this site :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [full mirror/archive of her website available](http://archive.sims.shanegowland.com/mirror/AdeleSims/adelevk.com/sims/index.html).